# convert javascript variable to a php variable using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have below code. I don't know much about ajax. I want below input  s_amount to convert as a php variable before submitting the form that it is in. There are some syntax errors where param1 in php code is not recognised. I don't know my order is correct or not. How I get this work.

```
<input type="text" name="s_amount" >
<script>
    $.ajax({
    url: 'payment.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {param1:$("input[type='text'[name='s_amount']").val()},
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log("response");
        responsen=response+1;
    })
    .fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
    });
   $param1=done(param1);
</script>

<?php
    $myphpvariable= $_POST['param1'];
    echo 'this is my php variable: '.$myphpvariable;
?>
```

Comment: If anybody can help me to find the error with my code I will be very grateful. I can't find where i got wrong

Comment: From your code, you haven't declared `responsen`, is this a typo?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you in understanding the concept.

```
 <input type="text" name="s_amount" >
 <script>


 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
    context: "application/json",
    url: "payment.php",
    data:{param1:$("input[name='s_amount']").val();},
    success: function(msg) 
    {
         alert(msg);
    }
    })

 </script>
```

`payment.php`

```
 <?php
     $myphpvariable= $_POST['param1'];
      echo 'this is my php variable: '.$myphpvariable;
 ?>
```

The main thing here was the line

```
  {param1:$("input[type='text'[name='s_amount']").val()}
```

it was not fetching the value from the texbox.
change it to

```
  {param1:$("input[name='s_amount']").val();}
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Comment: Error message gives as Undefined index: param1 in php code

Comment: try changing variable name. from param1 to id.

Comment: It didn't work. does the variable in $_post contain $?

Comment: For me its working fine... Use the above code and check once again.

Comment: Will you plese tell me to where this php lines should come? Is it ok to put just after the end of script or should I do some binding thing just like click on a button?

Comment: The php lines should be present in payment.php page. see the updated answer.

Comment: I have no luck. same error

Comment: something or somewhere you are going wrong. try to figure out.

Comment: How this php lines know that the variable param1 is inside the script?????